# retrieving an attachment in a case via rest api

Tags: api, mobile, rest, app

i am trying to build an app using salesforce as backend. I want to access the attachment in the cases. i am able to see the attachment using the workbench :-

/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Attachment/00Po0000001rTqKEAU/Body-H "Authorization token:bearer token"

I am using this but i am unable to get the contents of the body... Its giving just a single  binary 2 when it actually has 43567 as the content of the attachment.

LEt me know if u anyone knows this

Comment: post your code.

Answer (score 0):

I simply used .toString() and I am able to read the data in the text file attached. 
 Here is the response:
 `Blob lstAttach = [Select Body from Attachment where ID = '00P9000000IUVOE'][0].Body;
system.debug(lstAttach.toString());` 
`29.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG
Execute Anonymous: Blob lstAttach = [Select Body from Attachment where ID = '00P9000000IUVOE'][0].Body;
Execute Anonymous: system.debug(lstAttach.toString());
Execute Anonymous: 
00:01:14.045 (45789804)|EXECUTION_STARTED
00:01:14.045 (45802522)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
00:01:14.087 (87858375)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|
00:01:14.087 (87952246)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|
00:01:14.087 (87962341)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|4663554
00:01:14.088 (88011818)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
00:01:14.089 (89231600)|EXECUTION_FINISHED`